# globally update all uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on a Dark mode for an application. The basic premise to have a toggle allowing users to switch between a dark and a light mode.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to update all `UITableViewCell's`. IE in 'light mode' the cells background color is whiteish and in dark more the cells background color is darkish.

Currently I am accomplishing this by using

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
   willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell
 forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    if(darkMode)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor     = darkBackground;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = darkTextColor;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor     = lightBackground;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = lightTextColor;
    }
} // End of tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

The problem is, when a user switches from dark/light I want all cells to be redrawn so that the backgrounds are updated. I can do this on a per table base by calling an individual `uitableview` `reloaddata`, but I want to have EVERY tableview already loaded in the application to reload. Is this possible?

Comment: dig into `UIAppearance` class

Comment: The problem with `UIAppearance` is the labels. For example a cell may contain both a textLabel and detailLabel which generally should not be the same color. I don't believe UIAppearance can help with that.

Comment: You can create your own subclass of UITableViewCell that conforms to UIAppearance and mark a custom setter with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov thanks, but I'm using third party libraries which display their own cells too. I guess I could fork them and add some customization. That just may be the solution.

Comment: As an option could be also to swizzle all `init` methods of `UITableViewCell`, and register them as an observers of `NSNotification` messages.

Comment: The parent `UITableView` would still need to know to redraw the cells. Swizzling the UITableView itself might do the job though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My currently solution is to swizzle UITableView's and add a notification handler. I'm not positive if this will be my final implementation as I'm still investigating. The quick code looks something like this:

```
#import <JRSwizzle.h>

@implementation UITableView (Swizzle)

+ (void) load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;

        const SEL deallocSel  = NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc");

        BOOL result =
            [[self class] jr_swizzleMethod: @selector(initWithFrame:style:)
                                withMethod: @selector(initSQLProWithFrame:style:)
                                     error: &error];

        if (!result || error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can't swizzle methods - %@", [error description]);
        }

        result =
            [[self class] jr_swizzleMethod: @selector(initWithCoder:)
                                withMethod: @selector(initSQLProWithCoder:)
                                     error: &error];

        if (!result || error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can't swizzle methods - %@", [error description]);
        }

        result =
            [[self class] jr_swizzleMethod: deallocSel
                                withMethod: @selector(SQLProDealloc)
                                     error: &error];

        if (!result || error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can't swizzle methods - %@", [error description]);
        }
    });
}

- (instancetype) initSQLProWithFrame: (CGRect)frame
                               style: (UITableViewStyle) style
{
    self = [self initSQLProWithFrame: frame
                               style: style];

    if(self)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

        [nc addObserver: self
               selector: @selector(themeChanged)
                   name: [SQLProAppearanceManager apperanceUpdatedNotificationName]
                 object: nil];

    } // End of self

    return self;
} // End of initSQLProWithFrame:style:

- (instancetype) initSQLProWithCoder: (NSCoder*) coder
{
    self = [self initSQLProWithCoder: coder];

    if(self)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

        [nc addObserver: self
               selector: @selector(themeChanged)
                   name: [SQLProAppearanceManager apperanceUpdatedNotificationName]
                 object: nil];
    } // End of self

    return self;
} // End of initSQLProWithCoder:

- (void) themeChanged
{
    [self reloadData];
} // End of themeChanged

- (void) SQLProDealloc
{
    NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [nc removeObserver: self
                  name: [SQLProAppearanceManager apperanceUpdatedNotificationName]
                object: nil];

    [self SQLProDealloc];
} // End of SQLProDealloc

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this repository: https://github.com/Draveness/DKNightVersion

In `UITableView+Night.m`, it replaces setters of `sectionIndexBackgroundColor`, `sectionIndexColor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check darkMode state in every controller with `UITableView` in `viewWillAppear` method and call `reloadData` if needed

Comment: `UITableView` does not support `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: It's method of view controller

Comment: Yes, correct, but I'm not using a UITableViewController. Just a UITableView. The two are not simply interchangeable.

Comment: You can update your `UITableView` in `viewWillAppear ` method of any `UIViewController`